# Automatically use model attributes in URL generating a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

Hello Rails Stack community! <3

I want to generate a public sharing URL to a model that should always include some hash to prevent URL guessing.

This is what I came up with:

```
# routes.rb
resources :reports do
  member do
    get '/public/:public_hash', to: 'reports#public', as: 'public'
  end
end

# In some view
public_report_path(@report, @report.public_hash) 
# /reports/1234/public/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx
```

This works *okay*, but I feel like there should be a more graceful way to do this from the routes definition. What I want to do is `public_report_path(@report)` which should include the `public_hash` automatically when generating the URL.

Something in the lines of:

```
# routes.rb
resources :reports do
  member do
    get :public, do |route_object|
      route_object.path.push(route_object.params.first.public_hash)
    end
  end
end

# In some view
public_report_path(@report) 
# /reports/1234/public/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx
```

I saw some solutions where the definition of `url_for` was overwritten I'd rather not overwrite core functionality. Then I prefer giving 2 parameters to the url helper instead.

Comment: I think the path helpers are built to pick the id from that, unless you do do something with `#to_param`. Im not 100% on that tho

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a lot of trouble and use uuids in your rails migrations?

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_postgresql.html#uuid

All you'd need to do is run this in your migration:

```rb
  create_table : reports, id: :uuid  do |t|
    t.timestamps
  end
```

Then standard rails routes, relationships etc will be respected.

Comment: There are some cases though where having seperate internal and external identifiers can be advantageus though.

Comment: I like the way you're thinking. But in my case, the UUID can be re-generated by the user to make any previously shared links inaccessible. I looked at a solution using `param: :public_hash`, but that only works if **all** resources go trough that path, not just one member.